BadJpqlGrammarException with predicate for joined collection using JPQL
I have the following query:
 @Query("SELECT distinct u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.groups g where (LOWER(u.givenName) LIKE LOWER(:pattern) OR LOWER(u.familyName) LIKE LOWER(:pattern)) " +
        "AND g.groupName = :group AND u.userType = domainobjects.enumeration.UserType.T")
Slice<User> findByNamesSubstringInSameGroup(@Param("pattern") String pattern, @Param("group") String group, Pageable pageable);

and I get the following error:

org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.BadJpqlGrammarException: Line 1:233 no viable alternative at input 'g.groupName=:group'; Bad JPQL grammar [SELECT distinct u FROM User u JOIN u.groups g where (LOWER(u.givenName) LIKE LOWER(:pattern) OR LOWER(u.familyName) LIKE LOWER(:pattern)) AND u.userType = domainobjects.enumeration.UserType.T and g.groupName = :group ]

Previously the query was like this
SELECT distinct u FROM User u, IN(u.groups) as g where (LOWER(u.givenName) LIKE LOWER(:pattern) OR LOWER(u.familyName) LIKE LOWER(:pattern)) AND u.userType = domainobjects.enumeration.UserType.T and g.groupName = :group

and it worked with Hibernate 5. Now I'm using EclipseLink 4.0 and both doesn't work.
Entities:
@Entity
@Table(name = "TUSER")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer userId;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "User_LdapGroup",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupId"))
private Set<LdapGroup> groups;

}

@Entity
public class LdapGroup {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer groupId;

private String groupName;

}

Any ideas?
UPD: renaming parameter to 'groupName' solved the issue.

I think problem is in "LEFT JOIN FETCH" Try simply LEFT JOIN. You don't need FETCH - your Relation is EAGER.

@WladimirDiskowski didn't help

Other suspect point: @JoinColumn(name = "userId") and @JoinColumn(name = "groupId"). I think your column in DB are user_id and group_id. If so - you should define relation with @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") and @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")

@WladimirDiskowski no, they are userId and groupId. And if I replace both params with ?1 and ?2 respectively — error goes away. Is that a bug in EclipseLink?

OK, it's possible that u use reserved word "group" in statement. Try to rename second parameter

@WladimirDiskowski after renaming parameter it has started to work. Moreover, after renaming it back again — it has started to work. Mistery

@WladimirDiskowski looks like 'group' is a reserved name. Finally, it doesn't work with 'group' but it works with 'groupName' for example.
